# Getting full info from dropdown selection (Flutter / Dart)

Tags: api, flutter, dart, dropdown

Im making a corona app and i want that if you choose a country from the dropdown it shows the amounts of infected, died and recovered people.
when i change the value item['Country'] to just item i get the all the info of the country i have chosen but then when i change _mySelection = newVal to _mySelection = newval['Country'] i get an error.

```
There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: Australia. 
Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value
'package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart':
Failed assertion: line 827 pos 15: 'items == null || items.isEmpty || value == null ||
              items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) {
                return item.value == value;
              }).length == 1'
```

If you know a solution on how i can get the info please let me know.

**Dropdown**

```
child: new DropdownButton(
                          hint: Text(Country, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.black),
                          ),
                          isExpanded: true,
                          items: data.map((item) {
                            return new DropdownMenuItem(
                              child: new AutoSizeText(item['Country']),
                              value: item['Country'],
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                          onChanged: (newVal) {
                            setState(() {
                              _mySelection = newVal;
                            });
                          },
                          value: _mySelection,
                        ),
```

**Statresbody example**
Countries contains all the countries with the same info Afghanistan has in this example

```
{
    "Global": {
        "NewConfirmed": 174744,
        "TotalConfirmed": 8764876,
        "NewDeaths": 6071,
        "TotalDeaths": 468396,
        "NewRecovered": 90678,
        "TotalRecovered": 4245126
    },
    "Countries": [
        {
            "Country": "Afghanistan",
            "CountryCode": "AF",
            "Slug": "afghanistan",
            "NewConfirmed": 346,
            "TotalConfirmed": 27878,
            "NewDeaths": 2,
            "TotalDeaths": 548,
            "NewRecovered": 302,
            "TotalRecovered": 7962,
            "Date": "2020-06-20T19:19:28Z"
        },
```

Comment: It seems that `Australia` is multiple times on `data`

Comment: It does this for every country and im almost 100% sure it is only once in data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Couple of comments

1. I'd say that It would be more natural to use country code as value for the drop down.
2. You can get the full country info from `data` when `onChanged` is executed.

Your code would be replaced by this

```
    child: new DropdownButton(
      hint: Text(Country, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.black),
      ),
      isExpanded: true,
      items: data.map((item) {
        return new DropdownMenuItem(
          child: new Text(item['Country']),
          value: item['CountryCode'], // <===== use country code as value
        );
      }).toList(),
      onChanged: (newVal) {
        setState(() {
          _mySelection = newVal;
          // I get full country info
          var country = data.firstWhere((i) => i['CountryCode'] == newVal);
          // do what you want with the selection....
        });
      },
      value: _mySelection,
    ),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a *Country* class ( it's your CountryCollection class ) like so :

```
class Country {
  String country;
  String countryCode;
  String slug;
  int newConfirmed;
  int totalConfirmed;
  int newDeaths;
  int totalDeaths;
  int newRecovered;
  int totalRecovered;
  String date;

  Country(
      {this.country,
      this.countryCode,
      this.slug,
      this.newConfirmed,
      this.totalConfirmed,
      this.newDeaths,
      this.totalDeaths,
      this.newRecovered,
      this.totalRecovered,
      this.date});

  Country.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    country = json['Country'];
    countryCode = json['CountryCode'];
    slug = json['Slug'];
    newConfirmed = json['NewConfirmed'];
    totalConfirmed = json['TotalConfirmed'];
    newDeaths = json['NewDeaths'];
    totalDeaths = json['TotalDeaths'];
    newRecovered = json['NewRecovered'];
    totalRecovered = json['TotalRecovered'];
    date = json['Date'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['Country'] = this.country;
    data['CountryCode'] = this.countryCode;
    data['Slug'] = this.slug;
    data['NewConfirmed'] = this.newConfirmed;
    data['TotalConfirmed'] = this.totalConfirmed;
    data['NewDeaths'] = this.newDeaths;
    data['TotalDeaths'] = this.totalDeaths;
    data['NewRecovered'] = this.newRecovered;
    data['TotalRecovered'] = this.totalRecovered;
    data['Date'] = this.date;
    return data;
  }
}
```

And try to create your *DropdownButton* like so:

```
child: new DropdownButton<Country>(
    value: selectedCountry,
    onChanged: (Country newValue) {
      setState(() {
        selectedCountry = newValue;
      });
    },
    items: countries.map((Country country) {
      return new DropdownMenuItem<Country>(
        value: country,
        child: new Text(
          country.country,
        ),
      );
    }).toList(),
```

To fill your *countries* List, you can iterate on each element of *Countries* and use the *fromJson* method of your *Country* class, then use a *setState* to add the element to your List.

Comment: Hello Simon, thanks for the answer! Im trying to use your answer but i was wondering what type is selectedcountry and when i test i cant seem to get countries.map

Comment: Simon i want to thank you for your help and the effort you put in, your amazing!

Comment: You're welcome. Do not hesitate to mark the answer as correct so that other people find it if needed